# class.<?????>method(XPath).select();

Tags: java, silktest

I have a following line of code:

```
silk.<DomButton>find(buttonSubmitSearchXPathMain).select();
```

I've never seen a method being accompanied by `<xxx>`. I have a few other methods like that with the same brackets but different words. Unfortunately I'm unable to read the source for this method. Can someone please explain what is it? Just a description of a method? What is a purpose of it? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a call to a static generic method. Have a look at this [article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html).
[Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) allow generic programming.

For example this is a generic class:

```
public class GenericClass<T>{}
```

where generic type T is determined at compile time while instantiating the class.

```
GenericClass<String> class = new GenericClass<String>();
```

You can force the generic type to be descendant of a particular type. Example:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends JComponent>{}
```

This is useful to allow generic programming because inside a method you can threat the generic type independently of which is its real type.For example:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends JComponent>{

     private T component;
     public void showComponent(){
            T.setVisible(true);  //you can call this method. T could be a JComponent or a subclass of it
     }
}
```

In your case you are specifying the generic type while calling the static method, because of its static nature it could be invoked without having an instance.